# Is it possible to update ubuntu to 16.04 without updating the kernel?

Tags: kernel

Is it possible to update Ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04 without updating the kernel?

Comment: Why would you need to update Ubuntu while keeping the kernel at the same version?

Comment: When you spent ours tweaking the kernel to get something to work ;)

Comment: If you failed to keep track of the "tweaking" and can't move your changes along to later kernels, you have failed to act reasonably.

Comment: Are you using DKMS to install drivers?

Answer (score 0):

No. The kernel is part of the 16.04 update so it will always get installed during the update.

But the old kernels you can pick from the grub prompt after upgrading to 16.04.